# How to write where condition in postgres-flask for dynamic values

Tags: python, jquery, database, postgresql, flask

I am looking for a solution to dynamically pass values into the where clause of my postgres query in a flask app.

client is the value that changes dynamically which i want to pass on to 'clientid'. the above method doesn't throw any error, but it is not filtering. the no of rows i expect is 3 but this query fetches everything from payments table

```py
client = 'ms0001'
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM payments WHERE clientid = clientid", client)
value = cur.fetchall()
for a in value:
    print(a[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM payments WHERE clientid = %s", ('client',))
```

Let me know if that works for you :D

Comment: I am getting the below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "c:/Users/praha/VSCode/myWorkspace/Applications/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM payments WHERE clientid = %s", ('client'))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting